# ACL on /dev/pts

Tags: linux, permissions, access-control-list

Is it possible to enable ACLs for files under `/dev/pts`?

OS is Gentoo Linux, and the kernel is 3.2.13 with grsec.

Comment: I wonder who was so kind to downvote without commenting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is an [old] patch for what I want to do [here](https://lwn.net/Articles/121773/), but it was rejected because of lack of use cases.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean ACLs as in the things you set with setfacl? No, the 'files' under `/dev/pts` are character devices.

`setfacl` only works for files and directories.

```
setfacl -m u:test1:r /dev/pts/2
setfacl: /dev/pts/2: Operation not supported
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to use ACLs on character devices?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Allow users to restrict who can `write` them

Comment: Well I dunno if there is anything since no xattr support on devpts.

Comment: ls -lZ /dev/pts
crw--w----. root tty  unconfined_u:object_r:user_devpts_t:s0 0
crw--w----. root tty  unconfined_u:object_r:user_devpts_t:s0 1
c---------. root root system_u:object_r:ptmx_t:s0      ptmx

Comment: @AndrewSmith I don't use SELinux